# Inserting two different tuples into a table with the same primary key in sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to insert in the following table ABC(user text, num int), 
Where user is **primary key** two tuples:

```
(aaa, 1)
(aaa, 2)
```

What is the result of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first insert will work *(if there is not already a row with that primary key)*.

And the second insert will fail : duplicate primary key.

Answer (score 0):

The second insert will fail as you already used that key in the table.